# jQuery tracker firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics

I am using jQuery to track GA events with the following code, basically it allows the programmers to build a GA customized GA event through basic "blocks" (like the position etc.)

```
function trackingGaEvent(page, position, object, type, genContent, list) {
    var genContent = genContent || 'Click',
        eventAction = genContent,
        eventLabel = type + " - " + position + " " + object;

    if (list) {
        eventAction = type;
        eventLabel = genContent + " - " + position + " " + object;
    }
    console.log(page, eventAction, eventLabel);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.gaTracking', function() {
        trackingGaEvent($(this).data('page'),
            $(this).data('position'),
            $(this).data('object'),
            $(this).data('type'),
            $(this).data('gencontent'),
            $(this).data('list'));
    });
});
```

My problem however is that it always launch the code twice. I've tried to add a .unbind() as I have seen suggested on this site, but when I do that it disables my data-toggle="dropdown" (I am using jQuery & Bootstrap) on the site, making the website rather non-functional.

I need to find a way to make my GA tracking code fire only once when clicked without disturbing the other objects comportment on the website.

EDIT: Here is a typical HTML object that I am tracking:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-dark gaTracking" data-page="pgHomepage" data-position="Recent Videos" data-object="Button" data-type="More Videos" title="View videos list ordered by release date">+ More videos/a>
```

EDIT2: For now, I am using onclick="trackingGaEvent()" directly in the anchor tag until I can find a way to get the jQuery way working. So it does work with the onClick directly in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be really helpful to see the HTML, but without seeing it, I'd guess that your event is propagating through *two* `.gaTracking` nodes, causing jQuery to see two triggering nodes of the appropriate class. Maybe give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gaTracking').on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        trackingGaEvent(
            $(this).data('page'),
            $(this).data('position'),
            $(this).data('object'),
            $(this).data('type'),
            $(this).data('gencontent'),
            $(this).data('list'));
    });
});
```

Notice we're listening to individual `.gaTracking` nodes now, not the document. That means we can prevent the events from propagating to the root, and hence prevent it from firing on a parent `.gaTracking` node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion however it did not work, it is still firing twice. I also tried using .one instead of .on but the same problem arise. As for the HTML, well, the website is NSFW so I can't really post the link here unfortunately.

Comment: If you `console.log($('.gaTracking').length)`, do you get the number you expect?

Comment: Does removing the bootstrap.js include change anything? ... Bootstrap does some `$.trigger('click')` business here and there.

Comment: No, it still fires twice :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to register the event instead of `.on`, so the handler will be only fired once.

Comment: But if a user clicks something twice (or a hundred times), it'd only be tracked *once.*

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan true, I misunderstood the "I need to find a way to make my GA tracking code fire only once when clicked"